# Output object array loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, handlebars.js

I have the following code. I'm trying to output each key value ("company" and "address") the different "city1, 2 ,3" object (list goes on and on in the real example). in to a `<p>` using javascript. I am feeling a bit lost since I've tried a lot of different ways but I can't get it to work. I believe it might be due to the structure. If it would only be one city there would be no problem.

```
var data = {
  "city1":
    [
      {
        "company": "Ica kvantum",
        "address": "Orrgatan 3-5"
      },
      {
        "company": "Hemköp",
        "address": "Allegatan 26"
      }
    ],
  "city2":
    [
      {
        "company": "Ica Nära",
        "address": "Centrumvägen 7"
      }
    ],
  "city3":
    [
      {
        "company": "Hora brothers kiosk",
        "address": "Rövsgatan 43"
      },
      {
        "company": "Microsoft",
        "address": "Husvägen 38"
      }
    ]
};
```

Comment: [Please show what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's reasonable within your product requirements, you might consider using list elements rather than a simple `<p>`. Try to use the appropriate `document.createElement` methods rather than building a string. Something like:

```js
var data = {
  "city1": [{
    "company": "Ica kvantum",
    "address": "Orrgatan 3-5"
  }, {
    "company": "Hemköp",
    "address": "Allegatan 26"
  }],
  "city2": [{
    "company": "Ica Nära",
    "address": "Centrumvägen 7"
  }],
  "city3": [{
    "company": "Hora brothers kiosk",
    "address": "Rövsgatan 43"
  }, {
    "company": "Microsoft",
    "address": "Husvägen 38"
  }]
};

var cityList = document.getElementById("city-list");
for (var cityName in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(cityName)) {
    var city = document.createElement("li");

    var cityLabel = document.createElement("p");
    cityLabel.textContent = cityName;
    city.appendChild(cityLabel);

    var companyList = document.createElement("ul");
    city.appendChild(companyList);

    var companies = data[cityName];
    for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; ++i) {
      var company = document.createElement("li");
      company.textContent = companies[i].company + ": " + companies[i].address;
      companyList.appendChild(company);
    }

    cityList.appendChild(city);
  }
}
```

```html
<ol id="city-list"></ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the `data` object using `for...in` and then iterate the array inside with `forEach`.

```
var body = '';

for(var city in data) {
    data[city].forEach(function(entry) {
        body += '<p>' + entry.company + ', ' + entry.address + '</p>';
    });
}

console.log(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ben's answer.  I personally like plain for..in loops over foreaches in javascript, but its a preference.

```
var data = {
  "city1":
    [
      {
        "company": "Ica kvantum",
        "address": "Orrgatan 3-5"
      },
      {
        "company": "Hemköp",
        "address": "Allegatan 26"
      }
    ],
  ...
};

var html = "";
for(var city in data)
{
    //you can append the city to the html here if you want
    // html += "<h2>" + city + "</h2>";
    for(var company in data[city])
    {
        for(var field in data[city][company])
        {
            html += "<p>" + field + ": " + data[city][company][field] + "</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It do look clean @Wayne but you see I have multiple "city" objects(?) named city1 city2 city3 etc. Does this mean I would have to iterate through each city at a time, or can loop through them all at one and output all "company" and "address"es?